# current user inside wordpress menu hyperlink

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom menu for buddypress in wordpress.

The links always contain the current user.
In this example the user "admin

/members/admin/profile/

What do i have to do so that the link always points to the current user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a link to members, *me* will be handled as the current user.
For example: `https://yoursite.com/members/me/` will take you to your profile.